# breadcrumbs automático

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

Como implementar em php os breadcrumbs para que fiquem automáticos? tem alguma biblioteca que faça isso? Já pensei em algumas maneiras de se fazer, mas todas são gambiarras horrorosas que nem vou postar aqui.

Já procurei no outros tópicos relacionados mas nenhum me ajudou, Se alguém puder me dar uma ideia de como fazer, fico muito grato.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "automático"?

Comment: Vamos dizer que estou na página inicial, depois eu vá para a página de administrar usuários e depois para adicionar usuários. Queria que o caminho fosse gerado tipo assim: Pagina inicial > Administrar usuários > Adicionar usuários

Comment: Digo automatico porque queria que não importa em que página do site eu esteja, ele gere o caminho que fiz para chegar até lá

Comment: E como o sistema identificará quais são as páginas intermediárias? As URLs do sistema seguem um padrão definido e constante? Você possui um mapa de URLs que o sistema se baseará? E considerando que tal informação possa ser extraída da URL, como será a relação entre a URL e o *label* a ser exibido no *breadcrumb*? Tem muita coisa em aberto na sua pergunta, sendo impossível responder da maneira que está, então votarei para fechar como insuficientemente clara. Se houver uma edição melhorando a pergunta, irei reconsiderar o voto.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer um mapa de url's e acho que não estou sabendo fazer, será que você teria algum exemplo de como fazer ou lugar onde posso encontrar?